# Array Question for simplilearn Full stack java Program

Tags: java, arrays, collections, modulo

I am trying to implement ...

When I run the application, it ...

I had expected it to return ... for the input N = ... and AR = ...

Here is the full code:

```java
    static long calculate() {
        final int MOD = 1000000007;
        long X = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
                if (AR.get(i - 1) < AR.get(j - 1)) {
                    X = (X * 1) % MOD;
                } else {
                    X = (X * pow(AR.get(i - 1), AR.get(j - 1), MOD)) % MOD;
                }
            }
        }
        return (int) X;
    }

    private static long pow(int base, int exponent, int MOD) {
        long result = 1;
        while (exponent > 0) {
            if (exponent % 2 == 1) {
                result = (result * base) % MOD;
            }
            base = (base * base) % MOD;
            exponent /= 2;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Please tell me what am i doing wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is AR and N in your example code?
What is the expected result? What's the problem? Are you getting an error? Is there any output or is the program not responding at all?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [ask] and take the [tour]. When posting a question, make sure that the formatting makes sense and others can easily read and understand your question as well as your code. Currently, this is not the case. You can [edit] your question to fix these problems.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the return statement at the outside of the code.

You should only use return statement for methods, not loops like "for, while, do-while".

You can learn how to return a value from [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) documentation from the official Oracle's Java Documentation website.

Which tells you:

> You declare a method's return type in its method declaration. Within the body of the method, you use the return statement to return the value.

Good luck!